# Appropriate use BaseAdapter class specifically getView method

Tags: android, performance, listview, gridview

So far I have seen several examples of applications that use `BaseAdapter` and `ArrayAdapter<?>`. but I am still not completely clear the reasons why should be that way.

The first example is extending from `ArrayAdapter<?>`, this example is used in ListView, the following is the getView method

```
@override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    Holder holder = null;

    // Holder represents the elements of the view to use
    // Here are initialized   
    if(null == row) {               
        row = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(LAYOUT_ITEM_ID, parent, false);                

        holder = new Holder();
        holder.titleTextView = (TextView)row.findViewById(android.R.id.title);            

        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Holder) row.getTag();
    }       

    // here do operations in holder variable example
    holder.titleTextView.setText("Title " + position);

    return row;
}

public static class Holder {        
    TextView titleTextView;     
}
```

now in a second example a found is used `BaseAdapter` on a GridView this is the getView method

```
// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

    return imageView;
}
```

My question is: for a proper use of an Adapter is necessary to use a "Holder" static class, what implications does this have on application performance and compatibility on multiple devices (min API 8).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not necessary to use a holder class; it's more important to make sure that you re-use convertView whenever possible as this has a noticeable speed improvement.  That being said, using a holder does offer even better performance, especially if you are displaying a lot of items, as getView won't have to inflate the xml every time.

This video explains this in greater detail:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: This also applies to GridView?

Comment: Yes it does.  Actually they even say in that video they GridView and ListView are almost identical

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd like to point you to the [World of ListView session](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) that was held during Google I/O '10. It'll be worth watching that presentation (or read through the pdf) to better understand the `ListView` mechanics and why a 'ViewHolder/RowWrapper' pattern can significantly speed things up.

There are basically two key ingredients to optimizing the `getView()` logic:

- Make use of recycled views (the `convertView` parameters that gets passed into `getView()`)
- Minimize the number of (expensive) `findViewById()` calls

In your first example, the ViewHolder pattern is applied to only inflate the row view if no recycled view is available - that's good. Secondly, it reduces the number of view lookups by tagging the row with a ViewHolder object, which acts as a wrapper for the `TextView` that was already retrieved earlier.

Your second example does not inflate a row view, but rather instantiates it at runtime. It still checks whether a recycled view is available and uses that if possible - again, that's good. Also, since the row view (or grid view in this case) is just a single `ImageView`, the `convertView` can simple be cast to an `ImageView`. Note that if the row/grid view would've consisted of **more than just a single view**, the ViewHolder approach from the first snippet would be the appropriate way to go.

That being said, since the row view in the first snippet is also just a single `TextView`, it could potentially be simplified using the same casting-convertView-approach as in the second snippet. Quite often row views will consist of multiple views though, so I'd suggest to always use the ViewHolder pattern, as that will give you most flexibility to accommodate future changes.